# Why aren't my 301 redirects with .htaccess file working correctly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, opencart, http-status-code-301

I have Opencart installed with SEO Urls, I have changed the structure of some pages and would like to do 301 redirects for the changed pages so no (external) links will break. However I have SEO Links active in opencart, this means some rewriting rules are activated and I guess these are interferring with my 301 redirect code.

The last line is my redirect. Instead of redirecting `http://keroproducts.ch/kaufen` to `http://keroproducts.ch/produkte/`, it will redirect to: `http://keroproducts.ch/produkte/?_route_=kaufen` which is not correct.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.keroproducts\.ch [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://keroproducts.ch/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]


Redirect 301 /kaufen http://keroproducts.ch/
```

Comment: You are trying to rewrite BEFORE turning the RewriteEngine On.

Comment: I have fixed that. But the problem persists, see updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

[http://www.itsadam.co.uk/opencart-301-redirect-not-working-seo-fix-*route*/](http://www.itsadam.co.uk/opencart-301-redirect-not-working-seo-fix-_route_/)

You have to add an ? behind the redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /kaufen http://keroproducts.ch/?
```